# How to convert image to c array (const unsigned char) using C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, c, vb.net, image

How to convert a `.bmp` file to C code array (`const unsigned char`) using C# or VB.NET?

Given the image shown here, to be convert and the output example:

[image: sampleimage]

```
const unsigned char gImage_testcarray[356] = { 

0X00,0X01,0X32,0X00,0X32,0X00,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XE0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X03,0X70,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X0F,0XD8,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X1E,0XF6,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X3F,0XF3,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X7F,0X03,0X80,0X00,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0XFE,0X00,0XC0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XF8,0X00,0XE0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X01,0XE0,
0X00,0X20,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X03,0XC0,0X00,0X30,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X03,0X80,0X00,0X18,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X07,0X80,0X00,0X18,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X07,0X00,0X00,0X0C,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0X0E,0X00,0X00,0X0C,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X0E,0X00,0X00,0X0C,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X1C,
0X00,0X00,0X06,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X1C,0X00,0X00,0X06,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X18,0X00,0X00,
0X56,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X18,0X00,0X00,0X12,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X18,0X00,0X80,0X02,0X00,
0X00,0X00,0X10,0XFC,0X87,0X82,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X11,0X0C,0X1D,0X72,0X00,0X00,0X00,
0X13,0X82,0X30,0X16,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X02,0X01,0X23,0XC4,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X02,0XFE,
0X1F,0XF0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X07,0XFE,0X3F,0X70,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X05,0X7F,0X3E,0X80,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X01,0XEF,0X32,0X70,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X03,0XFE,0X1A,0X40,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0X01,0XFF,0X1A,0XE0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X01,0XFE,0X08,0X60,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,
0XFC,0X0E,0XC0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XFC,0X07,0XC0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0XFC,0X03,
0X80,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X7E,0XFF,0X80,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X37,0XFF,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X1C,0X07,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X1F,0XE6,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0X1F,0XFE,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X0F,0XF0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X03,
0XF0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X03,0XF0,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X01,0XE0,0X00,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,
0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,0X00,};
```

Comment: `char` doesn't have a sign. And what language is `const unsigned char gImage_testcarray[356] = { 0X00,0X01,0X32,0X00,0X32`?

Comment: So you want a C# program that outputs a C file? What have you tried? The process is quite trivial, read all bytes and print them in hexadecimal format.

Comment: hexadecimal format does not match with the c array (given below convert c array)

Comment: Enigmativity- It is bmp to c array

Comment: Image converted to c array by using Image2Lcd v3.2. I looking to convert image in the same way.

Comment: @AjaiKumar - What is a "c array"?

Comment: @Engimativity Image converted to c array using c++ or c language.

Comment: `gImage_testcarray` is not a bitmap. I can't figure out what are the first two bytes `0` and `1` for. The next set of bytes is 0x0032 x 0x0032, which may correspond to 50 x 50 pixels, that's the size of the image.